# Drawing graph elements (nodes and edges) in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, graph

I need to build a simple online map editor and I'm intended to use leaflet (but can eventually use openlayers). How can I draw graph elements (nodes and edges) in leaflet (on top of a map). Specifically, I can draw linestrings (edges) and circles (nodes), but they are not correlated in any way, that is, the linestring is not an edge of the point since they are two different geometries. Hence, how can I draw graph elements, nodes and edges, where edges and nodes are associated.

Example:

Here, the circles should represent a node, while the polylines are the edges. However, the two geometries are not associated in any way, that is, I can't associate the edges with the nodes.

How do I draw a graph on top of such mach where I can add, retrieve, delete edges and nodes?

[image]

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/52686200/820534

Comment: I fear that both Leaflet and OpenLayers lack graph editing features. I believe that with JOSM you could handle your case because it maintains the topology between nodes and ways but you can't run it on a browser. This 20 years old Java applet is probably not exactly what you want http://vjojic.tripod.com/intro/intro.html.